Do electrons in cathode ray emit EM radiation as they are accelerated towards the anode according to classical laws of electrodynamics?
According to the laws of electrodynamics of classical physics every accelerating charge must radiate energy. In that case do the electrons produced in the CRT that are accelerated towards the anode due to the high potential difference between the electrodes also radiate em radiation?
If yes, what is the source of this energy that is radiated in this case. Kinetic energy or electro static potential energy?

Yes, accelerated charges radiate. During the acceleration the electrostatic potential energy of the power supply between the cathode and anode is converted into kinetic energy by the acceleration.


must radiate energy. This is incorrect. Accelerated charge radiates in the sense it produces EM field that decays with distance as $1/r$. Whether this carries energy or not is a different question, and depends on whether the charge is a point charge or extended charge distribution.


@JonCuster -  Has this radiation emitted by cathode ray electrons as they transit towards the anode (not the X - rays produced after they hit the inside of the glass tube) been experimentally detected? If yes, is all this radiation outside the visible region?

@JánLalinský - Could you kindly explain what you mean by 'whether this carries energy or not'? Is electron treated as a point charge?

@Learner  There's a sizable literature on synchrotron radiation: as a light source, it has certainly been detected, and used, for decades.   That's usually magnetic deflection acceleration, not simple linear acceleration, because the beam can be recirculated, for hours, with the electron source disconnected.

It is an accounting question, it depends on where we put the energy. For point particle, field energy is zero; for extended particles, it is not. The thing that is present and has effect on other charged particles in any case is the radiation field, not radiation energy.
